# Como verificar se a string digitada tem apenas '0' e '1'?

Tags: python, binary

Estou querendo validar se a string digitada representa um número binário, mas do jeito que fiz não está funcionando muito bem:

```
binario = str(input('Binário: '))
if '01' in binario:
    quebrar_string = [c for c in binario]       #Pega a string, divide por digitos, e adiciona a uma lista. ex: 101, divindo, fica: ['1','0','1']
    inteiros = []
    resultado = 0
    for c in quebrar_string:                    #Pega cada digito da string, e converte para inteiro.
        inteiros.append(int(c))
    inverter = inteiros[::-1]                   #Inverte a string pra facilitar os calculoss
    for c in range(0,len(binario)):
        resultado += (2 ** c) * inverter[c]     #Realiza o cálculo citado anteriormente
    print(resultado)                            #Imprime a conversão do binario para decimal
else:
    print('O número digitado não é um binário.')
```

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 4):

Ja ouviu falar em expressões regulares? A seguinte expressão regular pode te ajudar.

```
 import re
 teste = "101010"
 print(re.match("^[10]+$", teste ) != None)
```

O valor que você quer testar está na variavel teste (altere e teste outros). Se o resultado da comparação for verdadeiro é porque o número é constituido apenas de 1s e 0s.

Comment: beleeeeeeza irmão, vou verificar melhor esse módulo. E valeu denovo

Answer (score 4):

### Preâmbulo:

Mesmo a pergunta sendo:

> Como verificar se a string digitada tem apenas '0' e '1'?

Seu código apresenta outros problemas e o mais evidente é o excesso de processamento para realizar tarefas simples que são verificar e converter uma `entrada` cujo é supostamente a representação em de um número inteiro em binário.

Em *Python* são disponibilizadas algumas [funções embutidas](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) e uma dessas funções é a função [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int).
Essa função `int()` possui dois parâmetros `( x , base = 10 )` e possui a finalidade de converter `x` em um inteiro.
Quando o parâmetro `base` é informado esse outro parâmetro `x`, que nesse caso pode ser [`str`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) ou [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects), é convertido num número [inteiro](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) segundo a base numérica informada pelo parâmetro `base` e gera uma exceção do tipo [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) caso `x` seja do tipo certo porém com o valor inapropriado.

### Conclusão:

Existem várias possibilidades em *Python* de realizar essa verificação e posterior conversão de uma presumida representação numérica em binário contida numa string em inteiro.
Porém conhecendo essas informações, a cima mencionadas, é possível utilizar unicamente a função `int()` para efetuar a conversão e tirar vantagem do comportamento da função em gerar uma exceção quando alimentada com o valor inapropriado.
Para isso é possível realizar a conversão aninhada a um [tratamento de exceções](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) que atuará como um mecanismo de controle do resultado da conversão caso a conversão tenha ou não sucesso.

```
entrada = '110011101'

try:                                            #Inicializa um bloco de tratamento de erros...
    retorno = int(entrada, 2)                   #Atribui a retorno a conversão da entrada na base 2.
except ValueError:                              #Caso haja uma exceção do tipo ValueError...
    retorno = 'Há um algarismo não binário.'    #Atribui a retorno uma frase.

print(retorno)                                  #Imprime 413
```

Também é possível realizar a mesma tarefa sem recorrer a um tratamento de exceções.
Nesse caso é preciso realizar uma verificação de cada um dos caracteres da entrada para saber se são adequados a operação.
Para fazer a verificação de se todos os elementos de um iterável atendam uma determinada condição é possível utilizar a função embutida [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all), que apenas retorna `true` todos os elementos de um iterável sejam `true`, junto de uma [expressão geradora](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

```
c in '01' for c in entrada
```

Que pode ser lida assim:

> Para cada caractere `c` na `entrada`
> Verifique se `c` está contido na string `01`...
> -  se **sim** adicionando ao gerador um elemento `true`.
> -  se **não** adicionando ao gerador um elemento `false`.

Então a função `all()` irá percorrer todos os elementos produzidos com essa expressão geradora e somente retornará `true` caso todos esse elementos sejam `true` senão retorna `false`.

```
entrada = '11001111111111111111101'

if all(c in '01' for c in entrada):            #Verifica se a entrada é valida...
    retorno = int(entrada, 2)                  #Se a entrada é valida efetua a conversão e atribui a retorno.
else:
    retorno = 'Há um algarismo não binário.'   #Se a entrada não é valida atribui a retorno um texto.

print(retorno)                                 #imprime 6815741
```

Caso seja exigido que a conversão de base seja calculada pelo exercício é possível utilizar a função embutida [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que para cada integrante de um iterável é retorna uma tupla contendo uma contagem(iniciada do 0) e o próprio integrante.

```
entrada = '11001111111111111111101'

if all(c in '01' for c in entrada):            #Verifica se a entrada é valida...
    retorno = 0
    for c in enumerate(entrada[::-1]):         #Enumere do último ao primeiro cada caractere da entrada...
      retorno += int(c[1]) * (2 ** c[0])       #Converte o caractere de base binária para base decimal.
else:
    retorno = 'Há um algarismo não binário.'   #Se a entrada não é valida atribui a retorno um texto.

print(retorno)                                 #imprime 6815741
```