# Como posso somar estes numeros que estão passando pelo forEach?

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso somar esses números para obter o resultado final que seria a conversão de binários para decimais esta tudo praticamente "certo" mesmo na base da gambiarra kkkk...

Números que preciso somar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este resultado foi obtido após inserir numeros binários no meu input e "tratado" os valores na função abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da minha condicional existe a chamada de outra função e é nela que esta os problemas que quero resolver:

```
// CONVERT TO BINARY

function convertToDecimal(value){
   let valueBinary = value.split("").reverse();

   valueBinary.forEach((item,index) => {
      let potencia = 2 ** index;   
      


      console.log(item * potencia);

   })
}
```

O resultado desta função são numbers separados um em cada linha, eu preciso somar os valores e assim obter o valor final que seria a conversao para Decimal.

Comment: Veja se essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485619/como-verificar-se-a-string-digitada-tem-apenas-0-e-1/485627#485627) o ajuda.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando uma soma dos valores potencia.

Basta declarar uma variável que vai acumular a soma dos valores que você está mostrando no console.

Segue um exemplo:

```
// CONVERT TO BINARY

function convertToDecimal(value){
   let valueBinary = value.split("").reverse();
   let soma = 0
   valueBinary.forEach((item,index) => {
      let potencia = 2 ** index;   
      let resultado = item * potencia //guardar o valor que está no console.log da sua pergunta
      soma = soma + resultado //acumular os resultados em uma variável auxiliar
   })
   console.log(soma)
   return soma
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!